# Image Not Uploading From Form

Tags: python, django

I want to save and filter user’s objects in my django app. After inputting the below codes, the imagefield is not uploading any image to my database and it’s not returning any image in my template.

Models

```
class Fin(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='3 bedroom flat for lease')
    main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
    side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    guideline=models.TextField(max_length=1000)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title


 class FinForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=Fin
     fields=('title','main_view','side_view', 'address','city','state','guideline')
     exclude=('user')
```

Views

```
     def fincrib(request):
          extra_data_context={}
          #if there's nothing in the field do nothing.
          if request. method=="POST":
             form =FinForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                data=form.cleaned_data
                newfincribs=Fin(
                   user= request.user,
                   title=data['title'],
                   main_view=data ['main_view'],
                   side_view=data['side_view'],
                   address=data['address'],
                   city=data['city'],
                   state=data['state'],
                   guideline=data['guideline'])
               newfincribs.save()
             extra_data_context.update({'FinForm':form})
      else:
          form = FinForm()
          extra_data_context.update({'FinForm':form})
      extra_data_context.update({'Fins':Fin.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
      return render_to_response('post.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
     {% block content %}
        <form action="." method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
    <center> {{FinForm.as_p}}  </center>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </form>

         {% for Fin in Fins %}
             <tr>
            <a href="{% url profiles_edit_profile %}"> {{Fin.user}} </a> </p> </strong>
             <p>{{Fin.title}}</p>
             <p><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Fin.main_view}}"/></p>
             <p> <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Fin.side_view}}"/></p>
              <p> {{Fin.address}} </p>
              <p> {{Fin.city}}</p>
              <p> {{Fin.state}}</p>
              <p> {{Fin.guideline}}</p>
              {% endfor %}
           {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a number of things on the template and view layer.

Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Comment: enctype declaration on template, passing request.FILES to the form constructor in the view to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Read [binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) from django official docs. I think it can help.